# jquery script request not caching

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, caching, getscript

I am trying to cache a very simple javascript response. I am using rails and my views/projects/index.js.erb contains only the following:

```
          alert('hi');
```

and when I request

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    url : '/projects',
    dataType: 'script'
  });
```

I get the popup 'hi' and I see in my server log that a request to Projects#index action as js has been made to it.

Then without refreshing the browser and I do it again

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    url : '/projects',
    dataType: 'script'
  });
```

I see that the server still gets a request
can anyone spot anything that I might have missed?

Thank you!

Comment: No, no error in the console at all. I checked both firefox and chrome's console. and I am not getting any request logged in the server log; and I have already went ahead and create a new simple app just so that none other plugin/script or anything can be interfereing. just a naked barebone page now with nothing on it.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the jQuery docs wrong, but isn't the second param to getScript the callback function?

Comment: @BStruthers: Aha, you are correct. The settings should be passed to `$.ajax()` not `$.getScript()`. That's probably the issue.

Comment: so should I do $.ajax(url, {dataType:'script',cache:true})?

Comment: @Drackir:now it's not cached :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what's wrong. jQuery actually surround the incoming script with a  so that the browser evaluates the incoming code. But the caching mechansim merely saves the code as text and when one re-request, it returns the code as text but not evaluate it. Therefore, one needs to eval the code explicitly

Comment: surround the incoming script with a what?