# format.js is not manipulating dom once action caching enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, caching, action-caching

*Note: I am presenting a logic here what I am doing.*

**What I am doing:**

Think about the basic index action where we are listing products and with pagination. Now using remote-true option I have enabled ajax based pagination. So far things works perfectly fine. Take a look on sample code.

Products Controller:

```
 def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:order =>"name ASC" ,:page => params[:page], :per_page => 14)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @products }
     format.js
   end
 end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<div id="products">
    <%= render "products/products" %> // products partial is just basic html rendering
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true')
});
</script>
```

Index.js.erb

```
  jQuery('#products').html("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'products/products' ) %>");
  $('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true');
```

**So whats the problem:**

Now I want to enable action caching on this. But index.js.erb file is not manipulating DOM. If I remove the remote-true functionality then things works fine with caching.

For action caching I have added this line on the top of the controller:

```
 caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
```

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Problem is jquery code is not executing. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400083/jquery-script-request-not-caching) question

*I found out what's wrong. jQuery actually surround the incoming script with a so that the browser evaluates the incoming code. But the caching mechansim merely saves the code as text and when one re-request, it returns the code as text but not evaluate it. Therefore, one needs to eval the code explicitly*

**But how to solve this problem??**

Comment: Try `caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params.merge(format: request.format.to_s) }`

Comment: Could you check if caches_action also caches the partial you render? Open your browser console and check the response you're getting. In that case, your problem wouldn't be that it doesn't update the DOM but updates it with the same partial, therefore same results.

Comment: @mathieugagne New partial is rendering but its not updating the dom. Take a look on this post. I double checked no issue in javascript http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/

Comment: Not what I meant. What I meant is that possibly the partial rendered by your index.js.erb is being cached. So it's not throwing any errors, simply rendering the same partial again and therefore look like it wouldn't be updating.

Comment: No its changing.. I checked that thing..

Comment: @jvnill Js code is not executing when caching enabled. Else its working perfectly fine..

Comment: @jvnill PLease check update section of the question..

Comment: Just to make sure: the ajax-pagination does work when you switch off caching?

Comment: @nathanvda its working perfectly fine. I tried it by disabling browser javascript

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: my understanding is that the server-side caching somehow interferes with the ajax pagination. Does the ajax-pagination work if you turn off the server-side caching? If you turn off the browser javascript the ajax will not work at all (since you are not using javascript). I have had a problem where jQuery/browser was doing the caching, not the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what the issue should be with using `remote: true`. Someone else suggested to use `.ajax` instead of `remote: true`, but that's exactly what the remote functionality does, so there shouldn't be any difference.

The other answer has code that explicitly uses `jQuery.ajax`, but the only difference in their code compared to what the remote functionality does is that they're specifying an explicit `dataType`. You can actually do that with `remote: true` though.

In your HTML link, you just need to specify `data-type="script"`. Or, based on your posted JS, you'd do this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true').attr('data-type', 'script');
});
```

EDIT: Also, I wrote more in-depth about the data-type attribute and how it works with Rails here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error, I think I have a work around.

**Page links**

Instead of

`$(function() { $('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true') });`

use

```
$(function() {
  $('.pagination a').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: 'script'
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

so response created by the app server will be run as javascript

**Controller**

next, change your `caches_action` line to

```
caches_action :index, cache_path: proc { |c| c.params.except(:_).merge(format: request.format) }
```

since ajax appends a `_` params for some sort of timestamp

Hopefully this works :)

Comment: its not working :( Please check the updated section. I think that makes some sense..

Comment: remember that you need to clear your cache before you add this code. i've tested this one on a sample app and I can assure that it is working.

Comment: Also I am using remote=> true. and I am in a middle of a massive upcoming product..

Comment: hmm.. Lemme try that on a separate test application.

Comment: dont use `remote: true`. let ajax handle your links instead of relying on `remote: true`. btw, i forgot a `return false` inside the js.

Comment: Lemme try the same.. I will be back soon.

Comment: :) worked perfectly fine :) I have enabled this for my main page of the application but my application is heavily ajax based you can say its just 3 page application and there are more than 50 actions and all are done via remote true. How can we figure out that thing..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Bounty awarded :)

Comment: Ok, maybe accept the answer? So we know the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution to this problem. I have a controller that has `caches_action` for an action that uses format.js to fetch some data via ajax, and it was not working out of the box.

I found that, despite the request being transmitted to the server, and the server correctly parsing the request and "rendering" the `index.js.erb` template, nothing was updating in the DOM. Your solution with `$.ajax` and `dataType:'script'` fixed the problem for me, however, I didn't like having to do jquery to bind to a click on a link, which should happen by default... I was able to make it work correctly by changing my `link_to` to this:

`= link_to "click me", user_action_path(params), remote: true, data:{type: 'script'}`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem but on my 3.0.3 application with :remote => true I have added  :'data-type' =>: script and have been worked fine.

However, in my case, I don't see improvement when loaded by ajax the list.

Comment: @javi Problem fixed using this |c| c.params.except(:_)

Comment: I have used too, but if I don't put data-type => script don't work, response will not load.